# Command key as an event MODIFIERS value in iMacros script

Tags: macos, command, imacros, modifier

I have prepared a script for iMacros automation and there's a click event on a link but I want to open that link in a new tab. So, it can be achieved by pressing the command key when the event is being triggered for which I am using MODIFIERS as per the docs but I can't figure out how to use the command key in MODIFIERS value. I've tried 'cmd' and 'command' but it doesn't work.

`EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV" BUTTON=0 MODIFIERS="command"`

Answer (score 0):

I've figured this out, the value for the command key is "META" which I didn't know earlier.

Comment: Your Qt + Answer would make more "sense" (for other Users) if you mentioned your FCI... (Check my Profile on how to ask Qt's about 'iMacros' "correctly"...)